# Log4j2 TCP-SSL Appender configuration in log4j2-config.xml

Tags: ssl, log4j2, splunk

I am planning to configure a Log4j2 Socket Appender with a TCP-SSL Appender.

Here is the configuration I see in Log4j2 website.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <Socket name="socket" host="localhost" port="9500">
      <JsonLayout properties="true"/>
      <SSL>
        <KeyStore location="log4j2-keystore.jks" password="guessme!"/>
        <TrustStore location="truststore.jks" password="guessme!"/>
      </SSL>
    </Socket>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="socket"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

In this config, what do the `Keystore` and `TrustStore` files contain? I don't have these files.

I want to send my logs to Splunk TCP port.

Do I need to create `truststore.jks` with SSL certs from my Splunk server so that my server trusts Splunk?

What is `log4j2-keystore.jks`, and where can I download it? Do I need a `KeyStore` file? What should go in it? Does Splunk need a corresponding public key or trusted certs?

Answer (score 0):

The `keystore` contains your personal key and public key if you have and want to use them. It can be left out completely.

The `truststore` contains the server's certificate. You can download and package it as jks like this:

```
$ echo -n | openssl s_client -connect log-server.tld:5010 -servername log-server.tld \
| sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' | tee "server.crt"

$ keytool -import -alias log-server-certificate-alias -keystore log-server-cert.jks -file server.crt
```

The latter prompts you for the password you will then use in the log configuration.

I had a similar issue with logstash and posted a brief summary of my findings here: https://rekowski.info/home/technical/java/log4j2-socket-appender-logstash-kibana-ssl-tls.md